# WPF Loses Event Handler

Tags: wpf

I have a simple WPF app in .NET 4.7. The main Window listens for a "Key Up" event. If the Escape key is pressed, the Main Window closes itself. This works fine (at least it starts out working fine).

The main Window also contains a Button that opens another Window (call it X). X is just an empty Window. It has no event handlers. When X opens, the Button in the main Window is disabled. Once X closes, the Button is re-enabled.

Here's the problem: Once X is closed, the main Window's Key Up event handler seems to be gone...sort of. I can no longer press Escape to close the main Window *unless* I first give the focus to one of the buttons. If I just click on the main Window and press Escape, it will not close the Window. Prior to showing Window X, this was not the case.

It turns out that if I do *not* disable and re-enable the Button, the Key Up event handler continues to work after X is closed -- I can still reliably close the main Window by pressing the Escape key.

Obviously, I'm new to WPF. I'm wondering if there is something weird going on with Windows events.

Here is the the Main Window's XAML followed by it's code behind. I have also included Window X's XAML and code behind (btw, Window X is the `WrapPanelWindow`).

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_01.MainWindow" x:ClassModifier="internal"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_01"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Main Window" Height="300" Width="300" Background="#FF6289A4" KeyUp="Key_Up">

<StackPanel Margin="20,10,20,10">
    <Button Content="Canvas Example"/>
    <Button Content="WrapPanel Example" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="DockPanel Example"/>
    <Button Content="Grid Example"/>
    <Button Content="StackPanel Example"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the Main Window's code behind:

```
namespace Wpf_01 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    internal partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
            Window newWindow = null;

            switch(clickedButton.Content) {
                case "Canvas Example":
                    newWindow = new CanvasWindow();
                    break;
                case "WrapPanel Example":
                    newWindow = new WrapPanelWindow();
                    break;
            }

            if(newWindow != null) {
                clickedButton.IsEnabled = false;

                newWindow.Show();

                newWindow.Closed += (x, y) => clickedButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        } // Button_Clicked()


        private void Key_Up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if(e.Key == Key.Escape)
                Close();
        } // KeyHandler()
    }
}
```

Here is the WrapPanelWindow XAML and code behind:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_01.WrapPanelWindow" x:ClassModifier="internal"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Fun with WrapPanel Window" Height="200" Width="260">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Finally, the WrapPanelWindow's code behind.

```
namespace Wpf_01 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WrapPanelWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    internal partial class WrapPanelWindow : Window {
        public WrapPanelWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine. I suspect there is more code. If so, please post it. If there is any XAML that is related to these event post that as well. If we can't reproduce we can't answer your question

Comment: The added code looks fine. Make sure you clean the solution (right-click the solution in the solution explorer) and rebuild it. Set a breakpoint (F9) in the Key_Up method to see if it gets called.

Comment: @Erno - Breakpoints do not get hit. After X closes, I can then put the focus back on one of the Buttons and the Escape key will close the main Window. But if the focus is on the main Window itself, it do not work.

Comment: A couple of remarks: 1. on my machine, if the window has the focus it does work. 2. This setup will not scale if the user opens multiple window (as soon as one closes the escape button is enabled again) 3. A better solution would be to add all open windows to a list and only close the the window/app when the list is empty. (don't forget to remove closed windows from the list)

Comment: @Erno: That's weird that it works for you. In my case, once Window X is closed, a specific Button needs to have the focus before Escape closes the Window. I cannot, for example, simply click the Window's title bar and press Escape.

Comment: Here is my code compiled and tested with .Net 4.7.1: https://bitbucket.org/ernow/stackoverflowanswers

Answer (score 0):

The main window is not getting the focus back when you close the CanvasWindow. When you disable the button, nothing else on the window is focusable.

If you select the App from the windows taskbar (minimize and restore) or switch programs and come back using Ctrl+Tab it works.

Try giving the clickedButton focus after you re-enable it:

```
            newWindow.Closed += (x, y) =>
            {
                clickedButton.IsEnabled = true;
                clickedButton.Focus();
            };
```

Comment: The window can get the focus on my machine

Comment: @Edu: WrapPanelWindow has no controls at all, so there are no "focusable" controls. If you place a Key Up handler on WrapPanelWindow it will key the key event. So, it seems a Window *can* have the focus.

Comment: @Tom: There are two types of Focus. Keyboard and Logical. If no control has keyboard focus when the Window comes back it doesn't work. If any control has keyboard focus when the window is active again, then it works. Logical focus on the window only would not capture the keyboard inputs (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview)

Comment: I simply click the main window (title bar or free space) and it gets focus.

Comment: @Erno: You get logical focus but not keyboard focus.  (see learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/…)

Comment: My last comment (there are way too many here): it works on my machine